# Synchronize the size of controls that lay in different ItemsCollections

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I want to synchronize the width of two controls.

```
<!--DataContext-->
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" x:Name="HeaderDockPanel">
    <DockPanel  LastChildFill="True" MinHeight="60" DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding Month}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Month}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlock}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  />
        <!--this shoud to set the Width-->
        <!--Nested_1 DataContext  Model_1-->
        <local:DaysLine HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding ElementName=HeaderDockPanel, Path=DataContext.DaysHeaderWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DockPanel>

    <!--Nested_1 DataContext Model_2-->
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding CarBusiness}"> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <DockPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:CarBusiness}" LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlock}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="-6 0 0 0"/>
                    <!--this shoud to get the Width-->
                    <!--Nested_2 DataContext Model_3-->
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Business}" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalItemsControl}" Width="{Binding DaysHeaderWidth}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:BusinessTextBlock d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Business}" Business="{Binding}" ColumnWidth="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

The problem is that i can't find the source by `RelativeSource` `Binding` use `FindByName`.
The target control whatch on nested `DataContext` that is an item of the first and i cant set it in without adding to all this models the `MyWidth` property.

Is there a some enother way to bind them more correct?

I am thinking about a static property but it is not as correct as i want because i have planned to have a several instances of this control.

Comment: Why does your ListView have Grid.Row specified when it's inside a DockPanel? Did you mean instead to place both the inner DockPanel and ListView in a Grid with 2 rows so they would both stretch and have the same width?

Comment: Oh, it is my mistake. Sorry. Had moved it from grid earlier

Comment: Which binding fails?